# Combine 2 REGEXREPLACE Formulas Into One

Tags: google-sheets, regexp-replace

In cell C5, I have a date with dashes ---> 01-31-2013

I just need to remove the dashes, extract only the first 4 digits in the date (in this case, 0131), and append 'Efisd' at the BEGINNING of the string.

**So, the end result should look like this ---> Efisd0131**

---

So far, I've been able to remove the dashes, and extract the first 4 digits of the date. But, I can't seem to put append 'Efisd' to the beginning and put it all together into one formula.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks for your help.

[Here's the sample spreadsheet that you can edit](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TcZiq4Z_erL-JAxfAe_Tx8vJbJAW1Wam5YhKjn6HIuw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From just the input date you can get it done with this:

```
="Efisd"&left(substitute(B5,"-",""),4)
```

It substitutes the dashes for blanks, gets the left 4 characters, and ads Efisd to the front.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants the arrayformula version of this, here it is below. Put formula in very top cell in column, edit the header in between quotes, and change cell values to fit your spreadsheet.

```
={"Your Header";arrayformula(iferror(if(len(M2:M),"Efisd"&left(substitute(M2:M,"-",""),4),""),))}
```